# is it possible to "ignore" your .ssh when accessing a server?

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal, ssh-keys

I have started working somewhere. There are servers I've been given access to using a public key generated from my computer. However, while the ssh login seems to be fine at first, I can't actually grab the repo using this rsync. It wants a password I shouldn't need. I emailed the previous dev back, and suggested my terminal is ignoring ssh? Is this even possible? How would I fix that?

Need to access this code :/

Thanks for your help!

```
Last login: Fri Jun 13 11:51:30 on ttys000
Naomis-MacBook-Air:summerspirit.github.io Naomi$ cd
Naomis-MacBook-Air:~ Naomi$ ssh naomi@svn.civicrm.ca
Last login: Fri Jun 13 09:56:56 2014 from 76-10-147-186.dsl.teksavvy.com

[naomi@emily ~]$ ls
community.socialinnovation.ca socialinnovation.ca
[naomi@emily ~]$ ls -alt
total 28
-rw-------. 1 naomi naomi 183 Jun 13 12:43 .bash_history
drwx------. 3 naomi naomi 4096 Jun 13 10:03 .
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 naomi naomi 35 Jun 13 10:03 socialinnovation.ca -> /var/www/vhosts/socialinnovation.ca
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 naomi naomi 45 Jun 13 10:02 community.socialinnovation.ca -> /var/www/vhosts/community.socialinnovation.ca
drwx------. 2 naomi naomi 4096 Jun 13 09:56 .ssh
drwxr-xr-x. 15 root root 4096 Jun 13 09:12 ..
-rw-r--r--. 1 naomi naomi 18 Jul 18 2013 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--. 1 naomi naomi 176 Jul 18 2013 .bash_profile
-rw-r--r--. 1 naomi naomi 124 Jul 18 2013 .bashrc
[naomi@emily ~]$ mkdir yolo
[naomi@emily ~]$ cd yolo
[naomi@emily yolo]$ rsync -avz naomi@svn.civicrm.ca:/var/www/vhosts/socialinnovation.ca .
The authenticity of host 'svn.civicrm.ca (209.15.213.70)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 63:99:92:28:c3:dd:b8:eb:c0:ec:c5:3a:11:7a:0f:88.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'svn.civicrm.ca,209.15.213.70' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
naomi@svn.civicrm.ca's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
naomi@svn.civicrm.ca's password:
Connection closed by UNKNOWN
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [receiver]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(600) [receiver=3.0.6]
[naomi@emily yolo]$
[naomi@emily yolo]$ rsync -avz naomi@svn.civicrm.ca:/var/www/vhosts/socialinnovation.ca .
naomi@svn.civicrm.ca's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
naomi@svn.civicrm.ca's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
naomi@svn.civicrm.ca's password:
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [receiver]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(600) [receiver=3.0.6]
[naomi@emily yolo]$
[naomi@emily yolo]$ rsync -avz naomi@svn.civicrm.ca:/var/www/vhosts/community.socialinnovation.ca .
naomi@svn.civicrm.ca's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
naomi@svn.civicrm.ca's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
naomi@svn.civicrm.ca's password:
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [receiver]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(600) [receiver=3.0.6]
[naomi@emily yolo]$
```

from the dev 3:00 PM (19 hours ago)

to me, I'm thinking that your mac is somehow configured to ignore your .ssh keys when connecting.

Baffling, but reminds me why I'm not trying to run a public server ...

Comment: You generated your public-private keys via `ssh-keygen` on your Mac?

Have you setup `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server with your public keys?

Comment: I seemed to already have id's in my mac, so I just did
pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
and then copied the key, sent it to the other dev and he set it up so that I could access.
I can ssh in but I can't rsync.

Comment: How can this stuff be related with SVN?!

Comment: @summerspirit: my third option below shows how to use a local .ssh/id_rsa key pair on the remote server. However I'd recommend against that option in favour of option 1 or 2.

Comment: Also I agree, this doesn't seem to have anything to do with svn so I'd remove that tag.

Comment: If you can get on the server verify that `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` or `~/.ssh/authorized_keys2` have your keys. Also verify that `known_hosts` on both your and the remote system either don't contain info on your system or the information is correct. This is a system fingerprint used to verify that no one is spoofing your system.

Comment: And, yes. The server can be setup not to allow remote access without using passwords. This can be set via the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file. (This is the file on the Mac, but Linux should also have such a file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're ssh'ing from `Naomis-MacBook-Air` to `svn.civicrm.ca` (aka `emily`) and then you're trying to ssh again (via rsync) to `svn.civicrm.ca` from there.

Three possible solutions:

**1. rsync without the network**

Because you are trying to rsync naomi@svn.civicrm.ca:/var/www/vhosts/socialinnovation.ca *from* svn.civicrm.ca you could just use:

```
rsync -avz /var/www/vhosts/socialinnovation.ca .
```

By-passing the need to use ssh over the network at all.

**2. Make sure you are forwarding your agent**

The reason that your `.ssh` on `Naomis-MacBook-Air` is being ignored is because you haven't allowed ssh to forward your agent. You can fix this by running:

```
echo "ForwardAgent yes" > ~/.ssh/config
```

On `Naomis-MacBook-Air`. This should allow you to continue using ssh and rsync on `emily` once you have ssh'd onto that remote server.

You can test that has worked by running `ssh localhost` repeatedly - it should never ask you for a password!

**3. Copy your .ssh/id_rsa.pub and .ssh/id_rsa to the remote server and use them there**

This is what you tried to do with `pbcopy` in the comment on the original question.

Once you've got `/home/naomi/.ssh/id_rsa` and `/home/naomi/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` on the remote server, and once you have `chmod 400`'d both files, you should be able to:

```
naomi@emily:~$ ssh-agent bash
naomi@emily:~$ ssh-add
naomi@emily:~$ rsync ...
```

You have to do the manual `ssh-agent` and `ssh-add` commands because there won't already be an agent running that you can use. This is not the case on your MacBook Air because MacOS X runs an agent in the background for you.

However I would recommend against this option because it means putting your private key on the remote server, which anybody with root access on that server would then be able to access.